# How to Implement Transform Logic in unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, matrix, transform

I want to simulate the Transform operation in the thread, such as setting the parent node for it. What I can think of is to create a virtual Transform, and then record the localposition, localrotation, and localscale. But when I set the parent node for virtual transform, how do I update localposition, localrotation, and localscale? What is the conversion relationship between localposition and position, localrotation and rotation, localscale and scale?

Answer (score 0):

This is a general matrix mathematics problem, in Unity you can use [`Matrix4x4`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Matrix4x4.html). It is a struct and can be used completely independent from the Unity main thread.

Each virtual node can be a simple matrix created by `Matrix4x4.TRS`. Using `Matrix4x4.SetTRS` to change these values.

```
Matrix4x4.TRS(localPosition, localRotation, localScale);
```

In a nutshell if you have a parent node and a child node, to transform a vector from child's local space to world, you can call `Matrix4x4.MultiplyPoint` on each matrix from child's to parent's.

```
v = childMatrix.MultiplyPoint(v);
v = parentMatrix.MultiplyPoint(v);
```

The above process can be merged into a single matrix. You can cache it for efficiency.

```
childToWorldMatrix = parentMatrix * childMatrix;
v = childToWorldMatrix.MultiplyPoint(v);
```

The opposite operation (from world to local) only needs to call the same method on **Matrix4x4.inverse** from the reverse order.

```
v = parentMatrix.inverse.MultiplyPoint(v);
v = childMatrix.inverse.MultiplyPoint(v);
```

Comment: Probably also interesting for this: [`Transform.localToWorldMatrix`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform-localToWorldMatrix.html) and [`Transform.worldToLocalMatrix`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform-worldToLocalMatrix.html) ;)

Comment: um.tks for you answer.but i just want to kown what happend when i set the parent of transform . for example。gameobject a a.localposition = xxx, a.localrotation = xxx, a.localscale  = xxx and gameobject b b.localpostion = xxx,b.localrotation = xxx,b.localscale = xxx. call a.parent = b. how the a.localpostion,localrotation,localscale changend

Comment: @fangqiwu They are transformed by the parent's transform matrix from their world positions.